# how to compare groups and percentages within

Tags: hypothesis-testing, percentage

I am new to statistics and would really appreciate help. The people within the groups are different - how do I compare the percentages to see if there is a statistical significance between the groups that had training and between the group that did not

It looks something like this:

```
group 1           had training and worked
age group    number of tasks         percentage

20-25             40                  40
26-30             30                  30
31-35             30                  30 

group 2       did not have training and worked
age group    number of tasks         percentage

20-25             50                     50
26-30             10                     10
31-35             40                     40
```

Comment: A t-test isn't really suitable here (you mentioned it in your original tags). You probably want a chi-squared test for homogeneity of proportions (which will be equivalent to a test of independence because of the conditioning on both margins in the chi-square). This looks like routine bookwork -- is this for some class, or other form of study (even on your own)?

Comment: its for some research but gor confidentiality reasons could not disclose the exact nature

Comment: thank you very much for the response. the statistician does not work on laborday and i would also like to learn about this matter

Comment: "the statistician does not work on laborday" Is this some parochial reference? CV is an international site!

Comment: hi Nick, nope was just the way things were.